# Form Dialog like in Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my `asp.net` application and I need to add **form dialog** like in **Google Calendar**. If I click on some date, dialog is popup near the that date. not in middle of the page. and also page background is not get dark. (background is active)

I can create a form dialog using jquery. but I don't know how to popup dialog near the clicked date and keep page background active.

[image: Google Calendar]

How can I create a form dialog like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the `dayClick` callback, and use the `jsEvent` to position the jQuery UI dialog above the position where the mouse was clicked.

E.g.

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

      $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", {
                                  my: "bottom-10",
                                  of: jsEvent
                            });

      $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    }
  });
```

(Documentation for `dayClick`: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/)

For making sure that the background doesn't turn grey, you can set the `modal` option of the jQuery UI dialog to `false`:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ modal: false });
```

Comment: How can i add an **arrow head** like in above dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I have created a **plnkr**. You can call that function on `eventClick` callback for event details. You can call same function for select event too to display the quick event box. with the position absolute css you can show an arrow icon.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rp8EJ8MVKw6eG9NAdomP?p=preview